# resolve DNS for specific host over entire LAN

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx-server, nameserver

All machines on local LAN are working fine and using a UNIX box as their gateway and primary nameserver. DNS works great for the local domains the server manages and it forwards requests for domains it doesn't up to the ISP's namesevers. great!

Now, I'd like to change the hostname for a single host (not managed) to point to a different (local) IP for the machines on the LAN. How/where does one set that up? `etc/hosts` on the gateway? or are there some other files because it's acting as a nameserver?

Comment: what are you using for a DNS server on the UNIX box?  BIND? dnsmasq? djbdns?

Comment: Since it MacOSX, the answer is probably bind.

Answer (score 1):

The hosts file is for the DNS client component, even on a DNS server. Entries in the hosts file on the DNS server will be used by the DNS client component on the server, not by the DNS server component. you need to add/create the A record for the host in question in the appropriate DNS zone on the server.

Comment: Believe `dnsmasq` will use the /etc/hosts file by default when responding to queries.

Comment: Oh, my bad then. I'm a Windows admin exclusively. I should have paid more attention to the word UNIX in the question.